# KVM idle Windows guest using too much host cpu

Tags: windows, virtualization, cpu, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I know that there is alot of questions like this, but I tried many with no success at all.

I have the following host configuration:

```
Ubuntu Linux 16.04.1
Linux 4.4.0-64-generic on x86_64
AMD Turion(tm) II Neo N40L Dual-Core Processor, 2 cores
Real memory: 15.24 GB total / 6.37 GB used
```

And the following guest os installed:

```
Windows Server Core 2016 - 64 bits
```

The guest CPU is almost idle, as reported by power shell:

```
[10.0.4.135]: PS C:\gitlab> Get-Counter -ComputerName localhost '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' `
>>     | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples `
>>     | Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue `
>>     | Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending | Select-Object -First 20 `
>>     | ft InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100).toString('P')}} -AutoSize

InstanceName           CPU
------------           ---
_total                 198,82%
idle                   198,82%
sqlwriter              0,00%
msmpeng                0,00%
wlms                   0,00%
svchost                0,00%
labnetworkagentservice 0,00%
labagentservice        0,00%
msdepsvc               0,00%
svchost                0,00%
bash                   0,00%
wmiprvse               0,00%
msdtc                  0,00%
svchost                0,00%
wmiprvse               0,00%
conhost                0,00%
bash                   0,00%
wsmprovhost            0,00%
gitlab-runner          0,00%
svchost                0,00%
```

But host CPU kvm process is always high:

```
ID  Owner   CPU Command
24745   libvirt-qemu    50.2 %  qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name diagon-alley -S -machine pc-i440fx-xenial,a ...
```

Here is my domain xml:

```
<domain type='kvm'  xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>diagon-alley</name>
  <uuid>f57b9c74-ea50-11e6-b06d-076dfee54ac7</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>976562</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>976562</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <cputune>
    <vcpupin vcpu='0' cpuset='0'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='1' cpuset='1'/>
  </cputune>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-xenial'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='4095'/>      
    </hyperv>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough'>
    <topology sockets='1' cores='2' threads='1'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup' track='guest'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' cache='none' io='native'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/diagon-alley.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
    </disk>

    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/winserver2016-full.iso'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
    </disk>

    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/virtio-win.iso'/>
      <target dev='sdb' bus='sata' />
      <readonly/>
    </disk>

    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='08:00:27:4c:1a:f3'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>

    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>

    <graphics type='vnc' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>

<!--
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' vram='16384' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
--> 
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Is there anything else I can try to lower CPU drain? 
Thanks for any help

Comment: I've recently experienced the same issue with w2k12 and w2k16 in kvm. They would constantly use 20-30% cpu when they're in absolute idle. It took me ages to figure this out but it appears that you need to disable the clock syncing. Try running this `bcdedit /set {default} useplatformclock true` (more info [here](https://ispire.me/windows-7820082012-causing-high-cpu-loads-on-kvm/)) in your windows and hopefully it works for you as well.